# pregnancy superstitions or truth?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-basis, pregnancy

I am 4 months pregnant. I'm still a student and have to go out almost everyday. I even feel like going on an outing or a small picnic. But my in-laws don't allow me and my husband to do so. What does islam say on this. Is there any prohibition on a pregnant women moving out of house?

Also, is there any such thing that makes it compulsory for a pregnant lady to wear an iron bangle in order to protect herself. I haven't heard of any such thing but my in-laws force me to follow such this. Is this just superstition or is there any truth in all this?

I'll be thankful.

Comment: These are mainly cultural superstitions and traditions passed on from generation to generation. Pregnant woman are fully capable of going on and maintain quite a similar lifestyle. Some even work until very few weeks before the baby is due.

Comment: It is cultural interference in religion. the not going out of house is mainly originated by the fact that in old days healthcare was weak and thus threat of infections and such, and a few cultures associate not going out with evil eye and such. these things are true but that doesn't mean that you don't go out at all. As for the bangle it is complete superstition, essentially thought of keeping bad things away from oneself.  These things are nothing to worry about, pure s u p e r s t i t i o n !.

Comment: Also when surah falak and surah nas were revealed, prophet sallallahu allaihi wasallam used to recite these two surahs and mainly there opening ayats (called mu-aw-widatain) for protection (for oneself) from all bad things.

Answer (score 1):

salaams sister.

these are just superstitions, and cultural beliefs, not really backed up with religious rulings. Regarding the bangle, some people may even classify that as shirk, because it is similar to (for example) wearing a blue bead or something for 'luck' to protect you from the evil eye (this is just an example of course). the reason why some people classify it as shirk is because some believe that this item will protect them, and forgetting that Allah SWT is the sole protector. Some people even believe if they dont have that particuar item on them, some injury or harm will befall them. This is very similar to your case, and i would only advise you to remember that Allah SWT is the sole protector, and any good or bad that befalls is all from Him as only Allah SWT knows what is best.

Answer (score 0):

Falak, i never hear there are any prohibition on a pregnant women moving out of house. But surely this is an good advice to you to caution with your pregnancy.

my country knows "iron bangle" is "jimat" or fetish.

from this site : http://muslimah.or.id/aqidah/menyelamatkan-generasi-dari-syirik-jimat.html

> Prophet sallallaahu 'alaihi wa sallam said, "Whoever hung the amulet he has committed shirk." (HR. Ahmad, Hakim, of Friends' Uqbah bin' Amir al-Juhani)

The Prophet sallallaahu 'alaihi wa sallam when he saw someone wearing brass ring in his hand, then he asked,

> "What is this?"
>
> The man answered, "The antidote is sick."
>
> The Prophet said, "Let it go, because he will only add to the weakness
> in you. If you die while the ring was still there on your body then
> you will not be lucky forever. "(HR. Ahmad)

as Muslims we should believe wholeheartedly that benefit and harm it in the hands of God, so we can not rely hearts to Him. We must trust in Allah alone. Allah says,

> "..And in Allah alone should the believers put their trust.." (Qs.
> Ibrahim: 11)

Indeed charms can not resist and eliminate what God has ordained. Hope makes us noble educator who can produce a generation that is protected from the darkness of polytheism. Waallahu'alam.

How about my mother in law?

> "We enjoined upon man to be dutiful to his parents. His mother
> bore him in weakness upon weakness, and his weaning lasted two years.
> (We, therefore, enjoined upon him): 'Give thanks to Me and to your parents. To Me is your ultimate return. "(Qs. Luqman: 14)

Indeed mother-in-law is still the mother of your husband. One form of the wife to the husband's devotion is to serve the law. So Falak, keep being good and humble with your mother in law.

Answer (score 0):

First, about going out and doing picnic.

Modest Clothing is required for women to go out otherwise, it'll be like 'not obeying' what Allaah Subhanahu wata'ala prescribed for women to wear for their modesty in Quran.

Second, about iron bangle.

That's a total rubbish. (Harsh comment but I just can't constrain myself)

Wearing iron bangle or anything like that is not prescribed in anywhere in Quran and Hadith (As far as I know).

And, as you are pregnant, you must take precaution about going out and doing picnic.

From Islamic Context, I would advice you to recite Quran (in your leisure time or, after the Fajr Prayer) in a silent portion in your room with full devotion to our Lord, Allaah Rabbul 'Alameen.

Reciting Quran, (Specific Chapter, like, Chapter al-Yaseeen, Chapter al-Kahf, Chapter Ar-Rahman) will be beneficial to you and your child who isn't yet born because reciting Quran brings about the attention of Our Lord, himself. A special kind of Tranquillity are brought down with Angels upon the reciter.

So, rather than acting upon those kinds of foolish superstition, I would suggest you stay with more tranquillity by reciting Quran and last and all, never miss prayers 5 times a day.

```
From my opinion, A pious woman will surely be rewarded by our Lord.
```

Stay safe.

And Allaah knows best.

Answer (score -2):

If your picnic Includes Male, then it would be Haram for you to go especially without your Husband, and it is also haram for a woman to travel without a mahram. & about the Bangle ? I am in total agreement to that its al superstition, yes it can get you carried away with shirk. please give dawat to your in-law(or whoever does these things) to leave such practices as they will sink into darkness to polythiesm(no curse can be as big as polytheism)